# Fedora 17 transparent Ethernet Bridge not forwarding IP traffic

Tags: linux, linux-networking

I am running on Fedora 17 with the latest ebtables and have been trying to setup a transparent bridge - using the following script, I send a ping through the bridged host and only see the requests on the bridge (among other traffic from eth0), BUT, arps and arp replies are making it through.

My host is setup - Client 192.168.1.10 <-- eth0  --> eth2 192.168.1.20

Ethernet script:

```
#!/bin/sh
brctl addbr br0;
brctl stp br0 off;
brctl addif br0 eth0;
brctl addif br0 eth2;
(ifdown eth0 1>/dev/null 2>&1;);
(ifdown eth2 1>/dev/null 2>&1;);
ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0 up;
ifconfig eth2 0.0.0.0 up;
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward;   
ebtables -P INPUT ACCEPT
ebtables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
ebtables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
ebtables -A FORWARD -p ipv4 -j ACCEPT
ebtables -A FORWARD -p arp -j ACCEPT
```

Any assistance would be great! Edit  - also tried ACCEPT for ebtable policy which seems to be working better

Comment: Does it work when ebtables is configured to accept all traffic? Are there any iptables rules? (iptables shouldn't be in the path, but I've seen it affect traffic before.)

Comment: ebtables does not work when set to accept all traffic.  I think there might be some sort of routing logic issue if I have a management interface installed (which has an IP on the same subnet)

Answer (score 0):

I would be looking at those ebtables entries first. I haven't heard of ebtables before but to me it looks like you're dropping everything. Are you really trying to build a bridging firewall? If not, you don't need the firewall rules.

Comment: Yes I am.  One of the things I noticed was that if I had a management interface installed, the kernel was trying to be "smart" and routing everything incorrectly... disabled the management NIC so packets go through the correct interface.  Secondly, Network Manager  disabled that nightmare.